# What was James Potter's animagus form?

Tags: harry-potter

"Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban":

> And that's how we came to write the Marauder's Map, and sign it with
>   our nicknames. Sirius is Padfoot. Peter is Wormtail. **James was
>   Prongs**." "**What sort of animal** --?" Harry began, but Hermione cut him
>   off.

Exactly right, Harry asks a great question here. What sort of animal is "Prongs" a nickname for?

We know that Sirius is Padfoot (Dog), Peter is Wormtail (Rat), but what animal did James transform into?

Comment: Did you finish the book yet?

Comment: @Kevin It's been a long time since I looked at any of this stuff. But I answered another Potter question and was referencing the book and came across this quote. I couldn't remember what his animagus was. If it's something obvious or whatever I can delete the question.

Comment: BTW: James Potter *was* an animagus -- that is "a wizard who can shape shift into an animal." I don't know that we have a name for just the animal form of an animagus.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Hence why I used the term that way. If you have a better term, edit the question or I can edit it if you have a different term.

Comment: @JMFB The only term I have ever seen that seems to fit is "animagus form", but I don't know the books in as much detail as others... I'm looking :)

Comment: @Wouter I would have accepted your edit but the community and other users axed it. It looks like somebody else put your edits in. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It was a Stag.

From *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban* in a conversation with Lupin, it is said:

> ‘Yes, your father was always a stag when he transformed,’ he said. ‘You guessed right … that’s why we called him Prongs.’
>   <sub><sub>**Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban: Chapter 22 -- Owl Post Again**</sub></sub>

Comment: Good answer, thanks for the quote. It's very direct and answers exactly what I asked with no additional commentary. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It was a stag.

More information about James Potter [here](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/James_Potter_I).

Comment: Please, for future answers if you are going to use a link, add a relevant quote that supports your point. Answers based exclusively in links are discouraged, as links may change or even disappear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is correct but as pointed out you should at least include a quote like the answer above. +1 vote from me and thanks again.